Magento2 site need reboot every night
I have setup my magento2 site on dedicate root server from Hetzner.The site is setup correctly and have no issues at all in magento logs or apache2 logs. I also checked most of my cpu is also free so is RAM, but for some reason my site stops working and becomes inaccessible until i reboot the server. Once rebooted it works again.Can anyone please guide what can be the issue?

You need to setup a monitoring tool for your site such as NewRelic or Dynatrace.

@KhoaTruongDinh it's just staging site with no traffic on it currently.

without further information is complicated to get into a reasoning on why. By experience, as you mention that you have to reboot the server at every night, the main concerns to review are:
a) check which cronjobs are running near the server getting stall. There might be processes that uses too much resources that kills the web server.
b) Check disk space. creating a backup will generate temporal files, which might fill the disk space and cause the issue. When restarted the temporal files are removed releasing the used space.
To avoid having the server overload when the crun runs, you can prefix the command with the nice command
nice -n 15 <your_cron_call>

this should avoid to block the resources when running, as they are on background. Still, the database might get busy during the cron running.
To avoid running the cron twice you can use the flock command and have a file to avoid running the command twice. Should be something like:
flock <path_to_magento>/var/cron.lock -c nice -n 15 <your_cron_call>


Thanks for answer, disk space is not an issue, yes i have disabled cron jobs and for now site seems to be running but i have to wait for 1 days more to confirm if it's really cron job that is causing the issue.

have you had the chance to confirm that the cronfiles where the issue? running with crons with "nice" command might help to avoid the issue... as adding a timeout and lock file for the command

yes I can confim it was cron issues, since it was staging site so I have disabled the cron. Can you please give complete command for what you are saying

@UsamaSohail I've updated my answer with your request. If the response was helpful you can mark it as the correct one or upvote it.
